# How to remove gridlines from the spreadsheet in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a code in google app script that can mail me the spreadsheet and everything works well. Below is the code I am using.

```
function convSheetAndEmail(rng, email, subj)
{
 var HTML = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(rng);
 MailApp.sendEmail(email, subj, '', {htmlBody : HTML});

 }

function doGet()
{
// or Specify a range like A1:D12, etc.
var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange()
var emailUser = 'xyz@gmail.com';
var subject = 'Test Email';


 convSheetAndEmail(dataRange, emailUser, subject);
 }
```

Now when I am receiving the mail from this script it looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRu5N.png)

But I don't want to have these Gridlines in my mail. Please advice what I am missing.

Comment: You are not missing anything, the function `SheetConverter.convertRange2html(rng)` uses this [library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter) I assume. If so, the function returns a HTML table which specifies that table has [`border ="1"`](https://github.com/mogsdad/SheetConverter/blob/master/SheetConverter/Code.gs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are using sheetConverter [library](https://github.com/mogsdad/SheetConverter/blob/master/SheetConverter/Code.gs). It returns an HTML code with border style element set to 1/1px. So you will have to explicitly replace all the occurrences of border tag in your HTML like so

```
function convSheetAndEmail(rng, email, subj)
{
  var HTML = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(rng)
  Logger.log(HTML)
  HTML = HTML.replace(' border="1" ',' border="0" ')
  HTML = HTML.replace(/border:1px/g,'border:0px')
  Logger.log(HTML)
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subj, '', {htmlBody : HTML});
}
```

Reference: 
[`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)